# Transform text into key value pairs

Tags: python

Given text like this:

```
"$key\n
some value\n
$another_key\n
another longer\n
value\n"

# continue this trend with keys on lines marked by special symbol in this case $ 
# with corresponding value on the following lines until we hit another key
```

What would be nice and terse way to transform that into lists like this

```
keys = ["$key", "$another_key"]
values = ["some value", "another longervalue"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $ at the start of a line to identify this is a new key, append it to the keys list and append a new blank string to the values list. Then every time you have a line which doesnt start with a $ you concat that value on to the last element of values as this line must be related to the current key. only when you read a new key do you create a new blank values element.

```py
data = "$key\nsome value\n$another_key\nanother longer\nvalue\n"
keys = []
values = []
for line in data.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('$'):
        keys.append(line)
        values.append("")
    else:
        values[-1] += line
print(keys, values)
```

**Output**

```
['$key', '$another_key'] ['some value', 'another longervalue']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "$key\nsome value\n$another_key\nanother longer\nvalue"
key = []
value = []
for i in text.split('\n'):
    if i[0]=='$':
        key.append(i)
    else:
        value.append(i)
```

Comment: what about the \n in the end of the string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( assuming `text` is the variable with text values in it ):

```
all_text = text.split('\n')
val_tup = [ (val, all_text[i+1]) for i,val in enumerate(all_text) if val.startswith('$') ]
keys, values = [ val[0] for val in val_tup ], [ val[1] for val in val_tup ]
```

Comment: This code doesnt compile since values is not defined

Comment: look at your values lis `['some value', 'another longer']` the OP wants the values list as `['some value', 'another longervalue']`

Comment: They main issue to this problem is that values for a given key might run accross multiple lines, thats the challange the OP is trying to overcome

Answer (score 0):

```
s = """$key\n
some value\n
$another_key\n
another longer\n
value\n"""
s = s.split("\n")[:-1] # we know the string ednwith \n
keys, values = [], []
for i in s:
    if i[0] == "$" and i[1] !="$":
        keys.append(i)
    else:
        values.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be like this?

```
from collections import defaultdict

text = """$key\n
some value\n
$another_key\n
another longer\n
value\n"""

def get_pairs(s):
    pairs=defaultdict(str)
    current_key=None
    for line in s.splitlines():
        if  line.startswith('$'):
            current_key=line
            continue
        pairs[current_key]+=line
    return pairs
```

get values you need with `pairs.keys()` and `pairs.values()`

BTW, the `\n` is redundant, `'''string'''` will have `\n` in it.